# Building libgcc, libsupc++ 4.6 with newer toolchain

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, makefile, cross-compiling

I try build libgcc, libsupc++ from 4.6 with newer toolchain like 4.8.3 or 4.9.1. When I try build with gcc newer than 4.6.4 I got error:

```
/home/user/toolchain/arm-linux-gnueabi-linaro_4.8.3-2014.04/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-g++ -Os -fno-builtin -fno-common -ffreestanding -isystem ../libbase/include -isystem include -Ilibsupc++ -Ilibgcc -DIN_LIBGCC2 -mfloat-abi=soft -marm -march=armv7-a  -c /home/user/project/lxx/libsupc++/array_type_info.cc -o libsupc++/array_type_info.pic.o -fPIC -DPIC
In file included from /home/user/toolchain/arm-linux-gnueabi-linaro_4.8.3-2014.04/arm-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.8.3/arm-linux-gnueabi/bits/c++config.h:426:0,
                 from libsupc++/exception:39,
                 from /home/user/project/lxx/libsupc++/typeinfo:36,
                 from /home/user/project/lxx/libsupc++/tinfo.h:26,
                 from /home/user/project/lxx/libsupc++/array_type_info.cc:25:
/home/user/toolchain/arm-linux-gnueabi-linaro_4.8.3-2014.04/arm-linux-gnueabi/include/c++/4.8.3/arm-linux-gnueabi/bits/os_defines.h:44:19: error: missing binary operator before token "("
 #if __GLIBC_PREREQ(2,15) && defined(_GNU_SOURCE)
```

I tried add flag -nostdinc++, but I got error:

```
    /home/user/toolchain/arm-linux-gnueabi-linaro_4.8.3-2014.04/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-g++ -Os -fno-builtin -fno-common -ffreestanding -isystem ../libbase/include -isystem include -Ilibsupc++ -Ilibgcc -DIN_LIBGCC2 -mfloat-abi=soft -marm -march=armv7-a -nostdinc++ -c /home/user/project/lxx/libsupc++/array_type_info.cc -o libsupc++/array_type_info.pic.o -fPIC -DPIC
    In file included from /home/user/project/lxx/libsupc++/typeinfo:36:0,
                     from /home/user/project/lxx/libsupc++/tinfo.h:26,
                     from /home/user/project/lxx/libsupc++/array_type_info.cc:25:
libsupc++/exception:39:28: fatal error: bits/c++config.h: No such file or directory
#include <bits/c++config.h>
                            ^
compilation terminated.
```

My flags

```
CFLAGS = -Os -fno-builtin -fno-common -ffreestanding -isystem ../libbase/include -isystem include -Ilibsupc++ -Ilibgcc -DIN_LIBGCC2 \  
    -mfloat-abi=soft -marm -march=armv7-a
```

Comment: clearly libsupc++/exception:39:28: fatal error: bits/c++config.h: No such file or directory is the error check your files and their permissions

Comment: bits/c++config.h are in include in toolchain, so -nostdinc++ is not good solution I think.